# Class variable reference to function changes to instancemethod

Tags: python, python-2.7, static-methods, class-method

I'm trying to call an external function via a class variable. The following is a simplification of my real code:

```py
def func(arg):
    print(arg)

class MyClass(object):
    func_ref = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        #MyClass.func_ref = func
        cls.func_ref = func

    @staticmethod
    def func_override(arg):
        print("override printing arg...")
        MyClass.func_ref(arg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(type(func))
    print(type(MyClass.func_ref))
    MyClass.setUpClass()
    print(type(MyClass.func_ref))
    MyClass.func_override("hello!")
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
[~]$ python tmp.py
<type 'function'>
<type 'NoneType'>
<type 'instancemethod'>
override printing arg...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 20, in <module>
    MyClass.func_override("hello!")
TypeError: func_override() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

The situation seems to be unchanged if I use `MyClass` in place of `cls` within the classmethod `setUpClass()`.

I would expect the type of `MyClass.func_ref` to be `function` after the assignment in `setUpClass()` which explains the `TypeError` I get when I try to call it. Why is the type of `func_ref` being changed to `instancemethod` when the value I assigned to it is of type `function`?

This only seems to be an issue in Python 2. Python 3 behaves as I would expect.

How do I get calls to the static method `MyClass.func_override()` to call `func()`?

UPDATE

I was able to get the above to work by applying the following patch:

```
@@ -14,7 +14,7 @@ class MyClass(object):
     def func_override(arg):
         print("override printing arg...")
         func(arg)
-        MyClass.func_ref.__func__(arg)
+        MyClass.func_ref(arg)

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     print(type(func))
```

While the above works, its not at all clear to me why I needed to do this. I still don't understand why the type of `func_ref` ends up an `instancemethod` when I assigned to it a value of type `function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the function through a `staticmethod` as follows:

```
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        #MyClass.func_ref = func
        cls.func_ref = staticmethod(func)
```

There's no need to play with @-based decorators in this case as you want to  modify how the method is bound to MyClass, not the general definition of `func`.

Why is this necessary?  Because, when you assign a method to class, Python assumes you'll want to refer to an instance (via `self`) or the class (via `cls`).  `self`, unlike `this` in JS, is only a naming convention, so when it sees `arg` it assumes it got an instance, but you passed a string in your call.

So, as as Python cares, you might have as well have written `def func(self):`.  Which is why the message says `unbound method func() must be called with MyClass instance as first argument`.

`staticmethod` means, "please leave this alone and don't assume an instance or a class in the first variable".

You can even dispense with the `setUpClass entirely`:

```
class MyClass(object):
    func_ref = staticmethod(func)
```

BTW: In 2021, 16 months past EOL, Python 2.7  has all the subtle fagrance of moldy gym socks.  Except less safe, virologically-speaking.

Comment: Thank you! The "Python assumes you'll want..." is exactly what I was looking for. I'd up 2.7's fragrance to moldy gym socks left in a hot car. But even with the stench, 2.7 is still mission critical for some large and expensive systems. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When `func_ref` is called, it's expecting a `self` argument, just like any other normal (instance) class method (see [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self) for discussions why). You can either add a `self` argument to `func` or make `func` a static method:

```py
@staticmethod
def func(arg):
    print(arg)

>>> MyClass.setUpClass()
>>> MyClass.func_override("hello!")
override printing arg...
hello!
```

Note that in either case `func` is now not normally callable as a regular function:

```py
>>> func('what does this do?')
TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

If you need `func` to be usable as a regular function, you can wrap it with another, qualifying function and use the wrapper in `MyClass`:

```
def func(arg):
    print(arg)

@staticmethod
def func_wrapper(arg):
    func(arg)

class MyClass(object):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.func_ref = func_wrapper  # use wrapper function

>>> MyClass.setUpClass()
>>> MyClass.func_override("success!")
override printing arg...
success!
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand that `func_ref` is now expecting a `self` argument, but why? I assigned it the value of a "normal" function - not a method. I want `func` to remain a "norrmal' function un-associated with a class (as opposed to any kind of method, static or otherwise)

Comment: @awm129 Updated to address your comment

Comment: Thanks again. The wrapper could work, but I really want to call `func` via my class variable. I figured out something that works, but it isn't at all clear to me why it works.